# Wrapping text with in a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane where I am setting the text from another class using `textPane.setText("")`

The text is wrapping around as I want but I want it to add a tab space at the beginning of a line that has been started because of a wrap around.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: in other words you need lines starting from the second one to get indented?

Comment: You would have to find out the character length at which the line wraps around, and then add your own logic for adding a tab in between.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier to do using styled HTML?

Comment: Swing text components use `views` to paint the text. You would need to customize the default view to paint the wrapped line indented. I have no idea how to do this. Probably best place to start is at [Stanislav's website](http://java-sl.com/articles.html) which contains various examples of custom view painting. Maybe you can find one close to your requirements which you can customize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need hanging first lines right?

You can use setParagraphAttributes() passing left indent and negative first line indent in the attributes.
Use

```
public static void setLeftIndent(MutableAttributeSet a, float i)
public static void setFirstLineIndent(MutableAttributeSet a, float i)
```

See the example http://java-sl.com/tip_hanging_first_line.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 8 spaces in a Tab indent, So do:

```
textPane.append("        ");
textPane.append(yourStringValue);
```

You could also just do:

```
textPane.setText("        "+yourStringValue);
```

That should get you the tab indent you are looking for.